# Issue with clarity Multiple app level alerts <clr-alerts>

Tags: angular, typescript, banner, vmware-clarity, clarity

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ojzegz?file=package.json

I am implementing multiple alerts using Clarity  component https://v3.clarity.design/alerts (when there is more than 1 alert, there will be carousel (with right and left caret) at the left side of the banner. There is also a X icon at the "right most side of the banner" (I'm not able to override the color in the stackblitz, but it is clickable just not visible as the background color is the same as banner) which will close the alert at the top when "onclick". In the implementation, I am using a service to pass/get the alert information from 1 component to other components

When click on "remove" button, it should add 1 alert to the existing banner.

I am facing the following issues with the clarity multiple alerts component:

1. after click "remove" multiple times, then click on X to close the alert one by one, the alert banner will close one by one, I then click 'remove' twice again, when click on X to close one of the banner, there is still 1 banner left. Notice that the entire banner is hidden even though there is still 1 banner left.

Note: at the stackblitz code, the x icon is not noticeable as the color is the same as the banner, but it is actually at the "right side of the banner", when click on the right most side of the banner, it will close the topmost banner.

I could only get the emitted boolean result from the clarity code which is (clrAlertClosed)="$event". If it is a bug at Clarity,  I am not able to override Clarity close function in my codebase. Does anyone face the same issue or have idea of the 2 issues above? THanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix it at stackblitz just now. The alert banner is able to close one by one.